# Hide password query param from Nginx error_log

Tags: nginx, logging, rate-limiting

I use Oauth2 password grant to generate access tokens for my clients. That means the user's password is sent as a query param:

```
example.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=MyUsername&password=MyPassword
```

I use the following `log_filter` in order to mask the password for authentication attempts from the Nginx `access_log`:

```
http {
    log_format hide_password '$remote_addr $remote_user [$time_local] "$request_without_password" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    ...

    server {
        set $request_without_password $request;
        if ($request_without_password ~ (.*)password=[^&]*(.*)) {
            set $request_without_password $1password=****$2;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log hide_password;

        ....
    }
}
```

---

I have now introduced rate limiting using Nginx's `limit_req`. All rate limited requests are logged to the Nginx `error_log`. The problem is that It does not seem possible to use a `log_filter` on the `error_log`, meaning a rate limited authentication request will be logged with the user's password visible, which of course is unacceptable. Since I want to keep track of rate limited requests, I don't want to disable the `error_log`.

**Is there a way to log rate limited requests in Nginx without the password visible as a query param?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not mean that the password needs to be sent as a query parameter, and the password should not be sent as a query parameter.  The values should be sent in the body, exactly as it is [specified in the Oauth protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2):

> The client makes a request to the token endpoint by adding the
> following parameters using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> format per Appendix B with a character encoding of UTF-8 in the HTTP
> request entity-**body**:
>
> grant_type
> REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "password".
>
> username
> REQUIRED.  The resource owner username.
>
> password
> REQUIRED.  The resource owner password.
>
> scope
> OPTIONAL.  The scope of the access request as described by
> Section 3.3.

See also [the example in the same section of the Oauth specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2):

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=A3ddj3w
```

So, follow the standard -- don't put it in the query parameter, and you don't have this problem.

Comment: I'm amazed I did not know this, thanks. It's not really an answer to my question, but it solves the problem regardless, so I'll take it.

Comment: It is actually possible that you would like to store some data in query, for example when you use a library that doesn't support setting custom headers. Again, it doesn't have to be passwords, so the standard can be irrelevant here.